# Warning '@(!isEditing || ...)' is not a valid value of attribute 'disabled'?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

(Tried both in Visaul Studio 2019 V16.4.0 or V16.4.1. Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers added)

I'm using the following code in Blazor to disable inputs.

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind="@v" disabled="@(!isEditing || ...expression omitted...)" />
```

However, Visual Studio warns that

> Warning   '@(!isEditing || ...)' is not a valid value of attribute 'disabled'

What's the proper way to disable the input by custom logic?

[image: Warnings]

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you running? I just tried your code and do not get a warning.

Comment: Visual studio  2019 with code cop package and another extension which checks code installed.

Comment: What is `...omitted...` ??   Post the actual code or create a [mcve]

Comment: @HenkHolterman, it's just some expressions returns bool.

Comment: No repro. I made that an answer. You need to ask a much better question. Really create that [mcve] and always state the versions, type of app etc.

Comment: @ca9163d9 Is your VS 2019 up to date? I'm on 16.4.1 and do not have this problem.

Comment: Click or Hover one of those warnings and see what information you can get. There always is a number (like CS001234)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug.

HTML warning when setting disabled attribute using Razor syntax #16833
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/16833

**Update**:

All the warnings are disappeared after my Visual Studio is upgraded to V16.4.2.

Comment: Hmmm   that issue is still open and it is specifically stated that the () in `@(...)` solve it. There probably is another issue overthere that ic closer.

Comment: In vs2022 I received the same warning -

Answer (score 0):

html `disabled` attribute acceptable value is *disabled* or no value.
The easiest way is to use an @if statement:

```cs
@if(!isEditing || ...omitted...)
{
   <input type="checkbox" @bind="@v" disabled />
}
else
{
   <input type="checkbox" @bind="@v" />
}
```

Comment: Blazor should make this unnecessary.

Comment: If you pass in a false value in Blazor, it will omit the disabled attribute. This answer is misleading.

Comment: @Kyle, Actualy, you're right, but the compiler warns. The issue is how to avoid compilation warnings.

Comment: There should be no compilation warning either, I tried it on visual studio 16.4.1 and do not have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary expression:

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind="@v" @((!isEditing || ...expression omitted...) ? "disabled" : "") />
```

Comment: Will this generate `disabled=disabled` or `disabled=`?

Comment: @John, not correct... If the expression is evaluated to true, then the attribute disabled is present, else it is missing. The disabled attribute is never assigned a value in HTML. It is either missing or present.

Comment: @enet you're right, thanks for pointing that out. I remember some frameworks allow you to do it that way, but seems it doesn't work that way with plain html. I've updated my answer.